How should I go about this proof about homogeneous polynomials?
Question
Let $f_1,…,f_s$ be homogeneous polynomials of total degrees $d_1<d_2\leq …\leq d_s$ and let $I=\langle f_1,\ldots,f_s\rangle\subseteq k$. Show that if $g$ is another homogeneous polynomial of degree $d_1$ in $I$, then $g$ must be a constant multiple of $f_1$.
Note:
I have earlier proved that if $f=\sum_if_i$ and $g=\sum_ig_i$ are the expansions of two polynomials as the sums of their homogeneous components, then $f=g$ iff $f_i=g_i$ for all $i$. And that if $h_l$ is the homogeneous component of $h=f.g$, then $h_l=\sum_{i+j=l}f_i.g_j$. The hint provided in the exercise asks me to use these results to do the proof above, but I can’t seem to know how this hint shows that $g=cf_1$, where $c$ is constant. Obviously, there is something I can’t seem to get here.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Suppose that $g(x)$ is an arbitrary member of $I$ that is homogeneous of degree $d_1$. We may write $g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^s g_i(x)f_i(x)$ for some functions $g_i(x)$. Write $g_1(x) = g_1(0) + h_1(x)$ where $h_1(x)$ doesn't have a constant term. Then you have that
$$g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^s g_i(x)f_i(x)$$
$$= g_1(0)f_1(x) + h_1(x)f_1(x) +  \sum_{i=2}^s g_i(x) f_i(x)$$
Since the terms of $h_1(x)f_1(x) +  \sum_{i=2}^s g_i(x) f_i(x)$ are monomials of degree $d_1 + 1$ or greater, by the first fact you proved these terms sum to zero. Thus you are left with $g(x) = g_1(0) f_1(x)$, which is of the desired form.

I have two questions: (1) how did you come up with $g_1(x)=g_1(0)+h_1(x)$? (2) in the later part of the proof, does this mean we will have $\sum_{i=1}^sg_i(x)f_i(x)=g_1(0)h_1(x)$?

For (1) this leads to separating the term of degree $d_1$ from the higher order terms. For (2), the sum will equal $g_1(0)f_1(x)$.

Oh, I see what you did with (1)! $g_1(0)$ should have a degree less than or equal to $d_1$. However, I am not particularly sure I can wrap my head around (2). If the sum equals $g_1(0)h_1(x)$, how does that help with the argument that $g$ is a constant multiple of $f_1$?

The sum is $g_1(0)f_1(x)$ not $g_1(0)h_1(x)$. The sum of the remaining terms is what equals zero, leaving us with that one term $g_1(0)f_1(x)$.

Yes, I meant we would have $\sum_{i=1}^sg_if_i=g_1(0)f_1(x)$. My question is, how does this show that $g$ is a constant multiple of $f_1$? (I think we need to somehow show that $g=cf_1$ if I am not getting it wrong).

Oh I see. It's the notation I'm using. I'm writing an arbitrary member of $I$ that is homogeneous of degree $d_1$ in the form $g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^s g_i(x)f_i(x)$. I've clarified my answer above.

Really appreciate the clarity you just gave. I guess I have one more question: the hint in the exercise says I should take $g=\sum_{i=1}^sg_i$, but we used $g=\sum_{i=1}^sg_if_i$ here. How can we go from one to the other?

I'm not 100 percent sure what the other hint was about, but it might have been to write a given $g_i(x)f_i(x)$ in terms of its homogeneous terms. That is, let $g(x)$ in the hint be $g_i(x)$ here, and the $f(x)$ of the hint be $f_i(x)$ here (in this case $f(x)$ just has one homogeneous term, itself.) But I don't think it is really needed.

Oh I see. Thanks.
